# How to loop through the indexes of each item in a PHP associative array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, indexing, associative-array

I have four items in an associative array as shown below.

[image: items in an array]

I want to loop through the first indexes of each of the items, then proceed to the next until I reach the end. So, for b1, I want to get 0, for b2 I get 1, for b3 I get 1, for b4 I get 1. Then I proceed to index two. For b1 I get 0, for b2 I get 0 and so on until I have gotten all the numbers at the four indexes. Here is my code below:
[image: code]

I succeed with getting the first index, but then the loop does not proceed to the next index as shown below:

[image: output of code]

Please any help would be greatly appreciated. I am relatively new to PHP

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I have done that. But still getting same issue. It's now giving me 0011 i

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Coders can read.

Comment: Still need `$j = 0;` before the loop, but you don't need `array_push`. Try replacing the array_push line with `$response[$i] = $j;`.

Comment: thanks a lot. I'll try that out

Comment: [this](https://3v4l.org/RFEtO) might help